# List differences between remote folder (sftp) and local one

Tags: ftp

I wish to find a windows program (preferably with GUI) that will compare recursively a remote folder (SFTP) and a local one.

I would like it to list all the files and folders that are different, deleted or added based on timestamp and/or filesize (with this a changeable option).

I am *not* looking for a program to copy any files in either direction, *just* a list of the differences.

Robocopy may be a possible answer, but I can't see how to achieve this using it, and the Richcopy GUI for it doesn't appear to have the list only option.

Many thanks!

P.S. I posted a similar but different question, but these requirements are definitely different, hence this question.

Comment: Have you got access to shell / command prompt on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, can do. SSH to a linux server.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Ah ok, that's fair enough. I am coming at this as a programmer, wanting to know if anyone else has edited any of the files I'm working on. But obviously, if it's better elsewhere that's fine by me! Thanks.

Comment: make a copy of your local directory, then use `rsync` to synchronize the local copy with the remote directory and finally, use `diff` between the original directory and the modified copy to find out the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=FolderCompare) and/or [Directory-compare](http://directory-compare-2.softonic.de/)

Comment: BeyondCompare looks like a very interesting prospect!

Comment: Yes, take alook here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Compare you can fnnd there some links to alternative software too, personally i use WINMERGE but more for Files not for folders.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any such program, but I can definitely suggest a way out.

How about running a command such as `dir /s /b` (unix `ls -R`) on both the servers and redirecting it to a text file and then comparing them both using your favourite compare program (WinMerge for ex).

You must run the same command on both local and remote servers though.